# Select strings that do not contain a certain pattern R regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a group of files from which I want to select those that do not contain the terms 'dataset' or 'eff'.

**DATA**

```
k <- c("Duct1/X SN5 F9MH.csv", "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH_dataset.csv", "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH_eff.csv", 
"Duct2/X F7 X300 E10.csv", "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10_dataset.csv", 
"Duct2/X F7 X300 E10_eff.csv", "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10.csv", 
"Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10_dataset.csv", "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10_eff.csv", 
"Duct4/X F7 X600 E10.csv", "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10_dataset.csv", 
"Duct4/X F7 X600 E10_eff.csv")
```

**CODE**

From what I've understood,I can use `[^...]` to exclude certain characters (denoted by `...`) from the results.

Trying this for `N`:

```
# Looking for N works 
> grep('.*[N].*', k, value = T)
[1] "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH.csv"         "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH_dataset.csv" "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH_eff.csv"    

# Looking for strings not containing N does not work 
> grep('.*[!N].*', k, value = T)
[1] "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH.csv"         "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH_dataset.csv" "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH_eff.csv"    

# Trying with ^ also does not work 
> grep('.*[^N].*', k, value = T)
 [1] "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH.csv"               "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH_dataset.csv"       "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH_eff.csv"          
 [4] "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10.csv"            "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10_dataset.csv"    "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10_eff.csv"       
 [7] "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10.csv"         "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10_dataset.csv" "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10_eff.csv"    
[10] "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10.csv"            "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10_dataset.csv"    "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10_eff.csv"
```

I can get results with `grepl` and use it to subset the character vector:

```
> k[!grepl(pattern = 'N', x = k)]
[1] "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10.csv"            "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10_dataset.csv"    "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10_eff.csv"       
[4] "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10.csv"         "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10_dataset.csv" "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10_eff.csv"    
[7] "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10.csv"            "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10_dataset.csv"    "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10_eff.csv"
```

For my actual use case (`dataset|eff`):

```
> k[!grepl(pattern = 'eff|dataset', x = k)]
[1] "Duct1/X SN5 F9MH.csv"       "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10.csv"    "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10.csv"
[4] "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10.csv"
```

but I'm looking for an approach using `grep(... , value = T)` because I don't want to store the character vector (`k`) - it is the output from another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep('N',k,value = T,invert = T)
[1] "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10.csv"           
[2] "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10_dataset.csv"   
[3] "Duct2/X F7 X300 E10_eff.csv"       
[4] "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10.csv"        
[5] "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10_dataset.csv"
[6] "Duct3/X600 F8 X600 E10_eff.csv"    
[7] "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10.csv"           
[8] "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10_dataset.csv"   
[9] "Duct4/X F7 X600 E10_eff.csv"
```

so in your case you can do:

`grep('eff|dataset', k, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)`